# What is the maximum length of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?

Tags: php, http, request-uri

I was wondering if there is a limit to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` itself since there seems to be no limit on storing string in a variable (php7). [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33874811/2656006)

So, if a user can somehow request using a very very large url (I know there are browser limits), will php store all of the request URI in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

EDIT: I am sorry this is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/417142/2656006). The said question addresses browsers' limit. What if someone uses [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062324/what-is-curl-in-php)?

Comment: Your webserver might also play a part in this - Apache has the [`LimitRequestLine`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline) directive, for instance, which defaults to ~8,000 characters

Comment: Yes, this seems like the answer. Thank you!